# Why SSLSocket support TLSv1.2 from API level 16+ but SSLEngine from API level 20+?

Tags: android, ssl, sslengine

I just want to understand the difference between SSLSocket and SSLEngine classes? I can see in android document TLSv1.2 available for SSLSocket from API Level 16+ but for SSLEngine TLSv1.2 available from API Level 20+
https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html
https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLEngine

I am trying to use have created a server using https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket which is using SSLEngine. My server works fine with android devices running on API level 20+ but giving UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL error a device running on API level 17 during the handshake.

Comment: `SSLSocket` is blocking. The `SSLEngine` is there to support non-blocking SSL, which very few have implemented successfully. They are two separate implementations of TLS, so it isn't too surprising that they got out of sync. in the release cycle.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Okay,  so do you have any idea how we can use SSLEngine for devices running API level 16+ with TLSv1.2?

Comment: According to what you've posted, you can't without going to API Level 20+.

Comment: Resolved this issue by using Conscrypt Security Provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by using Conscrypt Security Provider.